# Array in array vba

Tags: arrays, vba

i have to create an array in an array

here my code:

```
Dim servers(2) As String
Dim parameters(3) As String
Dim i, j As Integer

parameters(0) = "db1"
parameters(1) = "server1"
parameters(2) = "user1"
parameters(3) = "password1"

For i = 0 To 2
    For j = 0 To 3
       servers(i) = parameters(j)
    Next j
Next i
```

I made a graphical example with the result and i really don't know how to do it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uSme.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need a 2-D Array to populate your `servers`, try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub x()

Dim servers(2, 3) As String
Dim parameters() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

parameters = Array("db", "server", "user", "password")

For i = 0 To 2
    For j = LBound(parameters) To UBound(parameters)
       servers(i, j) = parameters(j) & i + 1
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems a user-defined type can help you:

```
Type tServerData
    DBname As String
    ServerID As String
    UserName As String
    Password As String
End Type

Dim ServerData(0 To 2) As tServerData
```

Now you have an arrray for 3 servers, for example:

```
ServerData(0).DBname= "db1"
```

etc.

Comment: UDT's are so under-rated. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try a two dimensional array:

```
Dim parameters(10,10) As String

parameters(1,1) = "db1"
parameters(1,2) = "server1"
...
parameters(2,1) = "db2"
parameters(2,2) = "server2"
...
```